# Hochschild homology computation of certain type

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, hochschild-homology

I know that in general Hochschild homology is not very computable. However, this certain type of Hoshschild homology shows up and I feel like there could be existing result.

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ be a $k$-algebra (commutative if necessary). Let $\alpha:A\to A$ be an automorphism of $k$-algebra and $A_\alpha$ be an $A-A$-bimodule defined by (1) as a $k$-vector space, $A_\alpha:=A$. (2) multiplication given by $a\cdot m\cdot b:=am\alpha(b)$ for $a,b\in A,m\in A_\alpha$.

I appreciate if someone could give some result or understanding related to $HH_*(A,A_\alpha)$.

Comment: If $A$ is commutative, $HH_0(A,A_{\alpha})$ is the quotient of $A$ by the ideal generated by $a-\alpha(a)$, and $HH_*$ is a module over that. For example, if $A$ is a field and $\alpha$ a non-trivial automorphism, the hochschild homology is zero.

Comment: @AchimKrause Yes these are all true. But I want much more, for instance if $A$ is smooth and $\alpha$ is nontrivial, what are all the homologies, instead of only the $0$-th.

Comment: Have you tried computing some examples, for example by explicit projective resolutions? I'm not sure whether one should expect a general formula, but it's certainly possible to compute any given example through some finite range of degrees.